# Finding max profit from buying and selling items (between an array of prices for a set of specific days) with limited storage capacity

Tags: python

My goal is to find the max profit that I can make from buying and selling items between days given an array of item prices for a set of specific days, i.e. {2.91, 2.775, 2.855, 2.89, 2.595, 2.99, 2.925, 2.685, 3.95, 3.56, 3.49, 3.92, 3.255, 3.195, 3.305, 3.39, 3.21, 3.33, 4.03, 4.05, 4.105, 3.565, 3.24, 3.335, 3.365, 3.26, 3.21, 3.525, 3.405, 3.35, 3.02, 2.755} (unit: $/weight). For this I will assume a limited storage capacity weight of 207400 (that means the total weight of all the items that we can buy and store in the storage is 207400) and no further limits on daily selling and buying of items.

I'm very confused, because this sounds different from the knapsack problem. So how can I solve this? (I'm using Python) I have been searching for similar questions but I couldn't find max profit with limited storage capacity. The most similar question is maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655167/algorithm-for-maximizing-shipping-profit-with-limitations-on-mass-and-cost. However, it has more limitations than my case and I still don't understand if this is exactly the knapsack problem or not.

I have been searching for similar questions but I couldn't find max profit with limited storage capacity.

This is the solution I have thought of, but I'm not sure if it actually gives max profit of buying and selling the items or not.

````py
# To store the dp values
dp=[]
 
def maxProfit(price, weight, n, max_W, max_E):
 
    # for each element given
    for i in range(1,n+1) :
 
        # For each possible weight value
        for j in range(1,max_W+1) :
 
            # For each case where the total elements are less than the constra
            for k in range(1, max_E+1) :
 
                # To ensure that we dont go out of the array
                if (j >= weight[i - 1]) :
 
                    dp[i][j][k] = max(
                        dp[i - 1][j][k],
                        dp[i - 1][j - weight[i - 1]][k - 1]
                            + price[i - 1])
                 
                else :
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[i - 1][j][k]
                 
 
    return dp[n][max_W][max_E]
 
 
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 32
    price = [2.91, 2.775, 2.855, 2.89, 2.595, 2.99, 2.925, 2.685, 3.95, 3.56, 3.49, 3.92, 3.255, 3.195, 3.305, 3.39, 3.21, 3.33, 4.03, 4.05, 4.105, 3.565, 3.24, 3.335, 3.365, 3.26, 3.21, 3.525, 3.405, 3.35, 3.02, 2.755] 
    weight = [9000,500,6007,980,2000,100,200,900,500,6007,980,400,100,200,90,500,6007,980,2000,100,2000,900,500,6007,980,400,100,2000,345,657,546,789]
    max_weight = 207400
#max elements that can be in the storage for a set of specific days    
    max_element = 33
 
    dp = [[[0 for j in range(max_element + 1)]for i in range(max_weight + 1)] for k in range(n+1)]
    print(maxProfit(price, weight, n, max_weight, max_element))
```
````

Comment: Have you tried a for loop? If so, can you share your code or why it didn't work

Comment: @GooJ above is the solution that I thought of.

Comment: @GooJ: I'm not sure if my solution actually gives max profit of buying and selling the items or not. And also when I give a total weight higher than the storage capacity(207400), it still returns a number as maxProfit but I want it to returns a message like: "Can't add this item, the total weight of items is higher than the storage capacity."

Comment: Seems like an (unclear) OR problem to me. You would have better chances to get an answer in the dedicated SE.

Answer (score 3):

That problem is often framed as a [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)  and solved with [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm). Kadane's algorithm only stores 2 scalar values so it uses very little space.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you can just buy 20 items (and weight doesnt matter) then you should use just the price (and not price/weight). If weight does matter then probably you want to find the price for how many fit in your backpack.
If you are wanting to find the best combination of items to buy for your backpack then you will need to use price/weight (but your calculation will be a bit more complicated than below and probably you want a seperate fuction to take these results then work out all the combinations and return the best combination)

Eitherway you could do something like this (I used a window of 20days):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'time': np.arange(40), 'price': np.random.random(size=40)})
df['max_difference_in_previous_20'] = [0 for i in range(df.shape[0])]
for start_time in range(20):
  end_time = start_time + 20
  sub_df = df.iloc[start_time:end_time].copy()
  max_difference_in_previous_20 = sub_df['price'].max() - sub_df['price'].min()
  df['max_difference_in_previous_20'].iloc[end_time] = max_difference_in_previous_20

print(df.tail(10))
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I am saying that storage capacity is 20, meaning the weight of our storage is 20.